# Postgresql's Schemas and Background Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, nginx, passenger

I'm running a Rails 3.2 app on Phusion Passenger, Nginx, and Postgres 9.1.4. I've moved my multi-tenant app to [Postgresql's schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html) (in development), following the method described in [this post](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/07/building-multi-tenant-rails-apps-with-postgresql-schemas/):

Since this approach seemingly sets the schema search path globally (via handle_subdomain, see below) for each request, how does this affect background jobs ([via Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/))?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :handle_subdomain

  def handle_subdomain
    if @tenant = Tenant.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
      PgTools.set_search_path @tenant.id
    else
      PgTools.restore_default_search_path
    end
  end
end
```

What happens if I then set the search path in a Resque background job that takes a decent amount of time (say, deleting a bunch of Paperclip images that are hosted on S3)?  Could this potentially interfere with a request to the app, which sets the path in handle_subdomain?

Should I patch ActiveRecord to hard code the schema search path?  E.G. select * from "1"."users" ("1" being the schema path)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ActiveRecord is just issuing "SET search_path = x" commands then that is setting the value per-session, so you should be fine.

In fact, if you set it inside an explicit transaction it will be rolled back at the end of the transaction if the transaction gets rolled back*.

- clarified following comment from araqnid

Comment: on the final point: that's true, but only if the transaction is rolled back, which I would have thought was not the normal case?